# Which of the following two sentences is more correct?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Please help me with next:

Which kind of sentence is more correct:

> a. We decided to present you Jim, Department Manager of Sam, as a contact person for ...
>
> b. We decided to present you Jim, Department Manager which employs Sam, as a contact person for ...

Comment: Could you provide some more context for this?

Comment: For example: We'd like introduce some person to another person.

Comment: Also the relative which shouldn't be used for animate, especially human things. Use who here instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of those sentences sounds quite right.

If I've understood correctly, perhaps something like this might be appropriate:

> We've decided to appoint you, Jim, as a contact person for Sam, given that you're his department manager.

**EDIT:** The questioner has clarified that the context is introducing one person to another. In that case, perhaps this would be appropriate:

> This is Jim, Sam's department manager. He'll be the contact for X.

Comment: Agreed. Shorter sentences are almost always better in business situations, where clarity is more important than quality prose.